# Shiny - Issues with Check Boxes and Filtering Data

Tags: r, shiny

I've been starting to learn Shiny to try and develop some nice simple interfaces and I've managed to put together my first one below thanks to modifying some code I found at https://gist.github.com/4211337.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

schedule<-read.csv("NBA_Schedule.csv")
stats<-read.csv("2015_2016_Stats.csv")

data_sets<-unique(schedule$Date)
data_sets<-as.character(data_sets)

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Game Date (US Time)", as.list(data_sets))
  })

  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    schedule_subset<-schedule[  schedule$Date %in% input$dataset, ]
    schedule_subset$Game<-as.character(schedule_subset$Game)

    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose Games to Include", 
                       choices  = schedule_subset$Game,
                       selected = schedule_subset$Game)
  })

  output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()

    schedule_subset<-schedule[  schedule$Date %in% input$dataset, ]
    teams_selected <- c(as.character(schedule_subset$VIS[schedule_subset$Game==input$columns]),as.character(schedule_subset$HOM[schedule_subset$Game==input$columns]))

    if (is.null(input$columns))
      return()

    stats<-stats[  stats$Tm %in% teams_selected, ]

    stats
  })
})

ui<-shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("2016/2017 NBA DFS (Draftstars & Moneyball) Data Summary"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("choose_dataset"),

    uiOutput("choose_columns"),
br(),
a(href = "https://gist.github.com/4211337", "Original source code")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("data_table")
  )
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Upon start up I get the following interface which I don't have a problem with:

[image: Interface on Startup]

Now, the functionality of the code is supposed to include teams in this table only if the players play for the teams that have their tickboxes selected. So on start up we currently have 5,463 entries which is entirely correct.

However, once I start unticking boxes, etc the table data starts returning funny numbers. If I select boxes individually then the correct numbers of rows will result in the table, ie 1767 for Knicks v Cavaliers, 1913 for Spurs v Warriors and 1783 for Jazz v Blazers. However, if I select only the bottom two matches then the table returns no results:

[image: Incorrectly Showing No Results]

Or if I select the first and last match then I only get the 1767 results for Knicks v Cavaliers.

[image: Incorrect Results]

Other combinations of tickbox selections give similar incorrect results.

I would appreciate it if anybody could find the error in my code to try and resolve this issue so that I can move forward.

Comment: Do you have the links to the `NBA_Schedule.csv` as well as the `2015_2016_Stats.csv`, please? I cannot reproduce this properly without the links. My guess is that the error happens in the `DT::renderDataTable()` function, still I need to verify that.

Comment: The csv files can be found here <https://www.dropbox.com/sh/foz5plmigso1mgq/AACsckiPhbAc7SyPPn9iAZxXa?dl=0> in a dropbox folder.

Comment: I used the DT::renderDataTable() function because I wanted to have a table that was able to be filtered and searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this solve the issues? I could reproduce it and now it seems to display correct results.

```
  output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    schedule_subset<-schedule[  schedule$Date %in% input$dataset, ]
    teams_selected <- c(as.character(schedule_subset$VIS[schedule_subset$Game %in% input$columns]),
                        as.character(schedule_subset$HOM[schedule_subset$Game %in% input$columns]))
    if (is.null(input$columns))
      return()
    stats_subset<-stats[  stats$Tm %in% teams_selected, ]
    stats_subset
  })
```

The issues seemed to have been caused by:

- inaccurate subsetting criteria (correct: `schedule_subset$Game %in% input$columns`)
- incorrect data manipulation 
  (correct: `stats_subset<-stats[stats$Tm %in% teams_selected,]`).

Comment: This works perfect, thank you very much. Very much appreciated.